# How can I solve this problem: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [HomeController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

Route/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oll2p.png)

issue in the attached picture occurs.

It's laravel 8.x.

Comment: Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controller\HomeController::class, index]); 
it's working, i guess.

Comment: oh, thx. it's solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Import the class in the top. I think you forget this.

```
use app\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
```

and then,

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class,'index');
```